# Can livedata be used just as listener inside presentor

Tags: android, mvvm, mvp, android-livedata

I am developing an eCommerce android application & preferring MVP. My question is can I user live data just as a data listener inside the presenter to get data from the model/repository?

Comment: yes, you can use.

Comment: Have you tried?  Does it work?

Comment: Use `observeForever` method on starting the presenter and `removeObserver` methods of `LiveData` on destroying the presenter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `LiveData` as Data Listener. Use methods `observerForever` and `removeObserver` of `LiveData` for the desired functionality.

refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observeForever(androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)

If you working with **Kotlin** you can take advantage of [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a better option called `SingleLiveEvent` using `LiveData`.

Using this you can communicate between your `presenter/viewModel` and `view/Activity/Fragment`.